# Can a three force member be subdivided into two force members?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics

[image: Image credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veYrZhX71jA&list=PLyqSpQzTE6M_MEUdn1izTMB2yZgP1NLfs&index=18]

The question can be better understood with the help of the given example.

**What I can think:**

*Member CD:* a two-force member.

*Member DEG:* Because member DEG is the largest structure among members EG, DE and DEG and it has three forces acting on it, it should be a three force member.

[image: Image credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veYrZhX71jA&list=PLyqSpQzTE6M_MEUdn1izTMB2yZgP1NLfs&index=18]

**What I can't think:**

*Members DE and EG:*
Why cannot these be taken as independent two force members? When seen independently, they both are acted upon by only two forces (forces Rex and Rey can be combined into one force and which then acts upon DE and EG in opposite directions), which qualifies the definition of a two force member (as according to [http://web.mit.edu/4.441/1_lectures/1_lecture15/1_lecture15.html#:~:text=The%20two%2Dforce%20principle%20applies%20to%20ANY%20member%20or%20structure%20that%20has%20only%20two%20forces%20acting%20on%20it.](http://web.mit.edu/4.441/1_lectures/1_lecture15/1_lecture15.html#:%7E:text=The%20two%2Dforce%20principle%20applies%20to%20ANY%20member%20or%20structure%20that%20has%20only%20two%20forces%20acting%20on%20it.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equilibrium of a member the net force and net torque acting on the member must both be zero.

For a two-force member the two forces acting on the member must be equal in magnitude, co-linear and opposite in sense.
That said a two force member can only be in pure tension or pure compression.

Consider your member $DEG$ and split it into two two-force members $DE$ and $EG$.

[image]

Member $EG$ has two forces $X$ acting on it which are equal in magnitude, co-linear and opposite in sense and member $ED$ has two forces $Y$ acting on it which are equal in magnitude, co-linear and opposite in sense.

So which force(s) balance out force $F$?